# Conditional formatting within groups

Tags: excel-formula

How to do conditional formatting of table cells within separated groups? One could create a pivot table to split groups into columns and then set formatting for each column but it is not what I want :(

So... let's assume we have data like below and we'd like each group to be gradient-colored from **red** for maximum and **green** for minimum. How do I do this *without a need o constant modification to formatting while groups change*?

```
|  **Group**  |  **Value**  |
| ----------- | ----------- |
| A           | 1           | <- green
| A           | 2           | <- red
| B           | 123         | <- red
| B           | 12          | <- green
```

Answer (score 1):

Two conditional formatting rules with formulas:

Max:

```
=$B1=AGGREGATE(14,6,$B$1:$B$4/($A$1:$A$4=$A1),1)
```

Min

```
=$B1=AGGREGATE(15,6,$B$1:$B$4/($A$1:$A$4=$A1),1)
```

Applied to the full columns A:B

[image]

Comment: This one is really great. Thanks. However, I won't get gradient with it, will I.

Comment: Nope missed that, not sure it is possible, leave open and maybe someone smarter has a way.